# ASP.Net MVC client side validation error - working for one button but not the other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, modelstate

I have a page with two submit butons; SaveAndContinue, and SaveAndExit. They are exactly the same except for CSS class and controller action.

The first one, SaveAndContinue will correctly validate client side and it will not post to the controller if ModelState.IsValid is false. Whereas the second one will completely skip the client side validation and post to the controller with ModelState.IsValid is false.

I'm using standard data annotations validation and nothing else is special. No fancy jQuery/AJAX functions.

Anyone any suggestions why one would work and the other not?

I'm using MVC 3, jQuery.validate, jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both buttons of type submit?

Comment: And what exactly is not working? What would you like to happen?

Comment: Yes, both buttons are submit, and are exactly the same except for CSS class and controller action. The second button is not is not validating on the client side before hitting the controller, whereas the first one is. What i want is for them to both behave the same, or at least understand why they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Are the submit buttons contained in different forms? If the submit button is not in the form that contains the inputs that have failed validation then the submit will still happen with no client-side errors.

Comment: That is an interesting piece of information Jason, thanks. However I can confirm that they are both on the same form.

Comment: I can still catch the validation in the controller in the usual `ModelState.IsValid` way, so I have a work around. I just want to understand why it is not happening on the client side for this second button. For example, is there some automatic wireup of the button triggereing the validation on the client for the first button, that needs to be setup explicitly for the second button?

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been found (thanks to Osh) and it was glaring me in the face.

One of the `CSS` classes used by the second button was a `'cancel'` class, which in itself didn't do much.

However, the validate function in `jquery.validate-vsdoc.js` specifically checks if the `'submitHandler'` is a button with the class `'.cancel'`, and if so sets the validator.cancelSubmit = true

```
this.find("input, button").filter(".cancel").click(function () {

validator.cancelSubmit = true;

});
```

Hope this helps someone else. :-)